# Output hours only with DateADD function

Tags: ampscript, datetime

I have a requirement to output only time from date/time field in a SalesForce campaign for an email I am working on.

I had to split up the date/time in order to format as desired.

```
SET @Delivery = [Customer_Delivery__c]
SET @DeliveryDay = FormatDate(@Delivery, "ddddd, MMMM d, yyyy", "", "en-US")
SET @DeliveryTime = FormatDate(@Delivery, "", "H:mm tt", "en-US")
```

Here is my output code:

```
%%=v(@DeliveryDay)=%% %%=DateAdd(@DeliveryTime, "-4","H")=%%
```

I should mention that I had an additional requirement to subtract 4 hours from the delivery time.

I did so by using the DateAdd function to subtract 4 hours. - Now the problem is that when I use DateAdd the output after running the code is:

Monday, October 1, 2018 **10/1/2018** 2:30:00 PM

I want to remove the **10/1/2018** line. - How can I exclude the duplicate output of the date?

Desired output should be:

**Monday, October 1, 2018 2:30:00 PM**

When I don't use DateAdd it does not give me duplicate date but I have to use DateAdd to display the correct time.

All help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the syntax you are using, but there are issues with splitting before subtracting the hours - if delivery time is before 4AM the delivery date should switch to the day before.

Could you simply not do the following:

```
SET @Delivery = [Customer_Delivery__c]
SET @DeliveryDayTime = FormatDate(DateAdd(@Delivery, "-4", "H"), "ddddd, MMMM d, yyyy", "h:MM tt", "en-US")

%%=v(@DeliveryDayTime)=%%
```

I.e. wrap the DateAdd so it is the first parameter of a call to FormatDate, and have FormatDate handle both the date and time from that value?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Phil!

I have the date and time split into two strings based on one attribute. The default output is: 9/21/2018 12:00 AM

What I want instead is: **Monday, October 1, 2018 2:30:00 PM**

`%%=v(@DeliveryDay)=%%` output is: Monday, October 1, 2018 which is what I want for the date.

For the time I'm using: `%%=DateAdd(@DeliveryTime, "-4","H")=%%`  except it is including an extra date.

I'll have to try your string when I get home, but the complete output I am looking for is: **Monday, October 1, 2018 2:30:00 PM**

Will mark answered if what you say works.

Comment: Hi Phil, following up. - Your updated script worked! 

The only thing now is that the time is output in military, is there a way to change to standard? - According to documentation I need to add "s" to the function, however there does not seem to be anymore room.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dateTimeFormatting.htm

Comment: I assume by "military" you mean 24hr clock, so for 8PM it's saying 20? If so, try changing from "H:mm tt" to "h:mm tt"? Like I said, I don't know AMP so I'm just guessing.

Comment: Correct, I was able to adjust to the correct output but I have one last caveat. - The new string you posted is still including the date along with the hours. This is the new output: **Monday, October 1, 2018 10/2/2018 2:30:00 PM** - Do you have any idea why this is happening? I feel the empty "" should suffice for leaving the date blank. Is there a way I could reinforce this so the the string will exclude **10/2/2018**?

Comment: Hey @AMPvoyager, I would have expected "%%=v(@DeliveryDay)=%% %%=FormatDate(DateAdd(@DeliveryTime, "-4","H"), "", "h:mm tt", "en-US")=%%" to not include the date in the output because we are explicitly calling FormatDate to only get the "h:mm tt" (12hr hours, minutes and AM/PM indicator). Is that what you are using now?

Comment: btw, looking at what you are doing over-all, I'm not really sure I understand why you would split things the way you have. By taking the date before subtracting the 4 hours, you have problems if the delivery time is planned for any time before 4AM. In this scenario the date would be wrong (since the value should be a day before). I would suggest you do everything in a single go. I'll add a further answer.

Comment: Apologies for following up so late. - I am marking this as correct since in essence it actually is correct. However, to help whoever winds up on this page we decided to go another route and use a custom text only field to output time. This was the easiest solution to get around off-set timezone and display the correct time to the recipient.

Thanks!